# How to turn off displaying stroke when using a path operation in Inkscape

Tags: vector, inkscape, stroke

I want to create a newspaper roll in Inkscape. My goal would be to only have the intersection of the yellow area and the the left circle. However, if I select those and then use path -> intersection, a remaining stroke around the original yellow object is still there.

Maybe I could create it with decreasing the area of the yellow part, but this is something that came up before as well, and I want control over it.

[image: have intersection of yellow polygon and the left circle]

[image: the result with additional stroke]

Thank you!

Comment: It seems you want to keep only 1 segment of the resulting 3 node path. With the node tool (F2), you can delete the unneeded segments and nodes from the path.

Answer (score 1):

Intersection works between fills, it always creates closed paths as a result.

What you seem to be looking for is Path > Cut Path. After that operation, remove the parts you don't need (it's only cut, but all pieces are still there).

If you don't like how it turns out (because the path's ends will still behave like normal stroked path ends, and the direction of their end caps will maybe not be what you want), consider converting the ellipse to a filled path with Path > Stroke to Path, then doing your intersection with a filled object.